# Close the tab from workspaceAPI

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, workspaceapi

Hi I need some assistance for one of the scenario, i am trying to open a ABC LWC Component from
another XYZ Lightning Web Component in which target XYZ LWC is Wrapped inside the aura Named as qwert component.
the problem is that whenever user clicks new sub tab gets opened,
is there any way if the tab is already open then close the existing tab and open a new tab everytime.

```
clickOnNext(evt) {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__component',
            attributes: {
                componentName: 'c_ABCComponent'
            },
            state: {
                c__ITC: this.ITCRe,
            }
        });
    }
    
<aura:component implements='flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:isUrlAddressable access:global'>
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id='WAPI'/>
    <aura:handler name='init' value='{!this}' action='{!c.init}'/>
      <c:AsdComponent3 />
</aura:component>

({
    init: function (component, event, helper) {
        let workspaceAPI = component.find('WAPI');
        workspaceAPI.getEnclosingTabId().then((response) => {
            let idOfOpne= response.tabId;
            workspaceAPI.setTabLabel({
                tabId: idOfOpne,
                label: 'Loading This Tab'
            });
            
        })
        
)}
```

closing the existing tab and open the new tab will help  me to resolve the issue..
kindly someone help me out

Comment: is there no solution available??

Comment: If you can please segregate the above code snippet to show what code is from which component then we may be able to help you out. Also name the component you are trying out, don't write `one component another component`. Frame the question properly so that we get to understand if we read it once or twice.

Comment: @NagendraSingh Apologies for not framing the questions properly, i have updated it properly ,,,and i am trying to do something like this.....https://salesforcediaries.com/2020/06/07/navigate-to-lightning-web-component-from-another-lightning-web-component/

Comment: Problem here is its keep on opening in the new sub tab for the console app

Comment: Is `clickOnNext` responsible to open a subTab?

Comment: is it is the button on the UI which invoke the target LWC wrapped in AURA

Comment: No I meant where is the method which opens up the subTab?

Comment: Yes clickOnNext method calling the aura component..named as componentName: 'c_ABCComponent'